# Wordnet synset - strange list index out of range Error

Tags: python, nltk, wordnet

I started working with nltk and I am attempting to generate a function that would allow me to pass in an adjective, extract the first synset from wordnet and print it alongside its antonym. Her is my code:

```
def placementOperator(wordItem):
   wordnet_lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
   placementItem = wordnet_lemmatizer.lemmatize(wordItem,'a')
   print("The placementItem is: " + placementItem)
   iterationSet = wn.synsets(placementItem, 'a')
   if iterationSet[0]:
       print(" This is the SS NAME : " + iterationSet[0].name())
       for j in iterationSet[0].lemmas():
           print("  This is the LEMMAAAA: " + j.name())
           if j.antonyms():
               print("   This is the RElATIONSHIP " + j.name(), j.antonyms()[0].name())
           else: print("    _______> NO ANTONYM!")
   else: pass
```

I am almost there, except that my interpreter throws a 'list out of range' exception. I know that I can't call a list position that doesn't exist and I know that this error occurs when one tries to do so. But since I am explicitly testing for this with *if iterationSet[0]* I am not sure how I am ending up with the error anyways.

Any advice would be highly appreciated.

Her is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Admin/PycharmProjects/momely/associate/associate.py", line  57, in <module> preProcessor(0)
  File "C:/Users/Admin/PycharmProjects/momely/associate/associate.py", line 54, in preProcessor placementOperator(each_element[0])
   File "C:/Users/Admin/PycharmProjects/momely/associate/associate.py", line 31, in placementOperator if iterationSet[0]:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, `wn.synsets(placementItem, 'a')` returned you an empty list. This can happen if `placementItem` isn't in wordnet.

Therefore, when you did `iterationSet[0]`, it throws an out of range exception. Instead, you can change your check to be :

```
if iterationSet:
    print( ....
    ....
```

instead of

```
if iterationSet[0]:
   print(...
```